# Blender : the cube weight paint not the same on the other side problem

Tags: weight-painting, unity

[image]
I painted all 3 vertices to 0 weight on one side of the the cube.
[image]
but when I painted the other side all 3 vertices, it appeared a more square-like shape.
[image]
In blender , it is not controlling the top-right vertex , completely fine.
[image]
But when I import to unity, it is controlling the top-right vertex in unity which is not I want.
So I went back to blender to paint 0 weight again on the top-right vertex ,but this did not work.

Comment: hello, could you please share your armature + cube? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sure, I uploaded.

Comment: please share share the link it has given (copy paste the URL)

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/112712b1ff22463d96dc79d268878b3b

Comment: select a vertex, open the N panel > Item > Vertex Weights and see what vertex group it is part of, it looks like some of them are slightly part of other vertex groups, you can remove it from unwanted vertex group if necessary, just click on the X button

Comment: oh it works , thx a lot boi !!:)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a vertex, open the *N panel > Item > Vertex Weights* and see what vertex group it is part of, it looks like some of them are slightly part of other vertex groups, you can remove it from unwanted vertex group if necessary, just click on the X button:

[image]

You could also use the weight paint brush in *Blend > Subtract* mode. If you use the *Mix* mode and put the Strentgh at 0, it won't remove from a group it is part of (which makes no sense to me), you really need to choose the *Subtract* mode. Also you could select some vertices, go in the *Vertex Groups* list, select the group you want and click on *Remove*, or dropdown panel and *Remove from All Groups* and reassign to the right group.